# Use Authorize.net API key with xero.com

Tags: authorize.net

Looking to integrate the Authorize.net API key with xero.com so clients that receive an invoice from xero can click "Pay Now" and enter their credit card information and payment to be processed by the Authorize.net gateway.

I tried to integrate with xero from their integration tools, but I can't seem to find where to integrate with API key without using their integration tools and apps since Authorize.net is not an integrated app of xero.com